# Is there a better way to sort through an array of objects to dynamically generate HTML elements separated by value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm looping through an array of objects to dynamically generate HTML sorted by one or more values found in the objects.

Data:

```
data = [ { value: "FirstValue", category: "FirstCategory" }, { value: "SecondValue", category: "FirstCategory" }, { value: "ThirdValue", category: "SecondCategory" }, { value: "FourthValue", category: "FirstCategory" }]
```

My solution starts by creating an empty array, iterating through objects in data checking whether categories array contains object category.

If category in categories, I find the HTML with the category value, append necessary values inside.

If category not in categories, I push the new category into categories array, create a new HTML div with the category value inside and append an HTML div with the object value inside that newly created category div.

```
categories = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    value = data[i][value]
    category = data[i][category];

    if (categories.includes(category)) {
        console.log("Category already in array");
        existingCatBlock = findHTMLWhereCatIsCat(category);

        newHTMLBlockWithValue = newBlock(value);
        existingCatBlock.append(newHTMLBlockWithValue);
    } 
    else {
        categories.push(category);

        newCategoryBlock = newBlockWithCat(category);
        newHTMLBlockWithValue = newBlock(value);

        newCategoryBlock.append(newHTMLBlockWithValue);

        mainHTMLContainer.append(newCategoryBlock);
    }
}
```

Current solution gets the job done, but maybe there are better, more elegant known ways to do this, especially in the case there were more values to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly for readability, I would try manipulating the array first, sorting it in the way you want them, and then afterwards add everything on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a dictionary from your data whose keys would be the categories and the values would be arrays with your categories values. [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be used to build it. This gives the following object:

```
{
  "FirstCategory": [
    "FirstValue",
    "SecondValue",
    "FourthValue"
  ],
  "SecondCategory": [
    "ThirdValue"
  ]
}
```

Then you can iterate over the entries of this dictionary using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build each category, add its children and insert the whole category in the DOM.

That way, you don't have to keep track of which categories already exist in the DOM. You just have to insert it once, with all of its children, thanks to the intermediate mapping of categories to values.

```js
const data = [
  { value: "FirstValue", category: "FirstCategory" },
  { value: "SecondValue", category: "FirstCategory" },
  { value: "ThirdValue", category: "SecondCategory" },
  { value: "FourthValue", category: "FirstCategory" }
];

const dataByCategories = data.reduce((acc, { value, category }) => {
  acc[category] = [...(acc[category] || []), value];
  return acc;
}, {});

const mainHTMLContainer = document.querySelector('#main');

Object.entries(dataByCategories).forEach(([category, values]) => {
  const valuesHTML = values.map(newBlock).join('');
  const categoryBlock = newBlockWithCat(category, valuesHTML);
  // A single appendChild is done for each category
  mainHTMLContainer.appendChild(categoryBlock);
});

function newBlock(value) {
  return `<div class="value">html for ${value}</div>`;
}

function newBlockWithCat(category, values) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('category');
  div.innerHTML = values;
  return div;
}
```

```css
.value {
  padding: 2px;
}

.category {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```